# How to efficiently store Adjacency List using numpy ndarray?

Tags: python, list, adjacency-list, numpy-ndarray

I tried creating an ndarray of lists and that didn't work.

```
adjacency_list = np.ndarray(10, dtype = list)
```

Whenever I try appending something, like this: `adjacency_list.item(2).append(3)`, I am getting an error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'`. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better/more efficient way to store adjacency lists?

Comment: That doesn't create an array of lists, but an array with 10 elements of `None` type (dtype list is not a valid option). Are you trying to create a list of lists and to append data to each of these lists?

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to create a list of lists but my number of lists is fixed, which is 10. So, I thought using numpy.ndarray is more efficient. So, what I tried to do was create an ndarray of lists instead.